# Validating date value using Hive functions

Tags: hive

I have a string column whose values are dates.  Some are valid (`yyyy-MM-dd`) and some are not.  How do I filter valid and invalid using only Hive?  I cannot use custom UDF or Spark, so it has to be using Hive functions only.

```
select * from date_test;
+-------------------+--+
| date_test.mydate  |
+-------------------+--+
| 2018-12-13        | => valid
| 2018-13-12        | => invalid
| 2018-04-31        | => invalid
+-------------------+--+

select mydate,to_date(mydate) from date_test;
+-------------+-------------+--+
|   mydate    |     _c1     |
+-------------+-------------+--+
| 2018-12-13  | 2018-12-13  |
| 2018-13-12  | 2019-01-12  | => to_date() casts it to valid value
| 2018-04-31  | 2018-05-01  | => to_date() casts it to valid value
+-------------+-------------+--+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sort of managed to get it, but I am open to other better approaches.

```
//valid date values
select 
   mydate,
   to_date(mydate) 
from 
   date_test
where 
   mydate = to_date(mydate); 

+-------------+-------------+--+
|   mydate    |     _c1     |
+-------------+-------------+--+
| 2018-12-13  | 2018-12-13  |
+-------------+-------------+--+


//invalid date values
select 
   mydate,
   to_date(mydate) 
from 
   date_test
where 
   mydate <> to_date(mydate); 

+-------------+-------------+--+
|   mydate    |     _c1     |
+-------------+-------------+--+
| 2018-13-12  | 2019-01-12  |
| 2018-04-31  | 2018-05-01  |
+-------------+-------------+--+
```